# Cordova inappbrowser: executeScript on loadstart

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, inappbrowser

Is it possible to executeScript() on loadstart event in Cordova inAppBrowser? Here is my standalone example I made to try to make it happen:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Standalone Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      var iabRef = null;

      function testFunction() {
        iabRef.executeScript({
          code: {'alert("It is alive! ALIVE!")'}
        });
      }

      function onDeviceReady() {
        iabRef = window.open('http://telegraph.co.uk', '_self', 'location=no', 'zoom=no', 'hardwareback=yes');
        iabRef.addEventListener('loadstart', testFunction);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Doesn't work for me though. Config.xml allow origin is set to *. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little bit of wandering I found that changing "_self" to "_blank" makes it work. So:

```
iabRef = window.open('http://telegraph.co.uk', '_blank', 'location=no', 'zoom=no', 'hardwareback=yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible to executeScript() on loadstart.Remove {} from alert part as follows:

```
         function testFunction() {
         iabRef.executeScript({
           code: 'alert("It is alive! ALIVE!");'
         });
       }
```

Hope this works

Comment: Nope, page is loading but alert is not firing.

Comment: I tested this.It is working.Does the url loading completely?

Comment: It seems so. Telegraph threw and error and closed, so I changed it to youtube, now it loads page completely. But no alert event still. Problem could be in the builder maybe? I use adobe Phonegap online builder.

Comment: May be.Better you install it locally.And make sure inappbrowser plugin is installed.

Comment: It is weird though. But thanks anyway for trying things out, it was very nice of you to actually test the code.